# Collaborating on a visual studio project

Tags: project-management, git, team, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

In our company I started to develop an ADDIN for a drawing application. The first results of this ADDIN were reviewed as successful by the direction and they want to increase the workload on the application. So they assigned 1 colleague (and possibly 1 more in the future) to the project. Currently my coworker isn't coding but doing some research about the product we make before he jumps in.

The code is done in visual studio.

But we don't have a clue how to manage 2 (or 3) persons coding on the same project. (please note that we are not professional coders but drafting engineers that know enough coding to make this ADDIN).

I have done some research there are some tools to work with

- GitHub
- Visual Studio Team Services

But how do you know what solution is best, and how do you get started with them? Or is something like this not required?

Comment: The best version control tool is the one you understand how to use.

Comment: And what do you do when you don't have knowledge of any of them?

Comment: Do a quick trade study and pick whatever (a) everyone else is using, (b) has good support, and (c) looks easiest to set up.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is **definitely** required.

GitHub and Visual Studio Team Services are both more than good enough to get the job done - just pick one, learn it, and move on.

They are both [Version Control tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) and are worth using even if it's a team of one.

The primary advantage to such a tool is that when someone makes a change to the code, it's very easy to identify that change and undo it if necessary.